# Firebase Store database map for booking date and time slot

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking to build an web application which allow users to make reservation for a date and time slots in that date. I tried to think for a database to use firebase store database to check whether specific date and time is taken or not.

Thank You

I'm going to create a collection with uid which will have following fields.

1. date field
   2.time slot
   Then, I will make query for the booking that users choose. Let's say user choose 1-03-2023 and 9:00AM slot. I will make query whether that date and time slot already existed in the collection. If the answeer is yes, I won't let user to make reservation.

Is there any better way to build this kind of database model?

Answer (score 0):

I also used Cloud Firestore for my apps, but the approach I used is a bit different. Your approach is very messy and although Firestore is very effective in managing queries, I would advise you to adopt a different structure.

Get the date and time that inserts the user and the data to add.

```
- reservations (Collection)
   - aaaa [year] (document)
       - MM [month] (collection)
          - dd [day] (document)
              - timeslots (collection)
                  - hh/mm [hour/minutes] (Document)
```

This way, after you get the selected date and time, you can point directly to the date and check if there is already a document with the same time.